# usage of md-icon with an svg-icon set in angular.material

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, angular-material

I'm trying out material.angular.io.
I want to use SVG-Icons from a single SVG file.
I followed the instructions from here
https://material.angular.io/components/component/icon
but I don't get a result when using md-icon with the iconset.
One icon per SVG file works.

This is my app.component.html:

```
<!-- works -->
<md-icon svgIcon="thumbs-up"></md-icon>

<!-- works -->
<svg class="svg-24px">
  <use xlink:href="./assets/img/svg/svg-sprite-action-symbol.svg#ic_favorite_24px"></use>
</svg>

<!-- works not -->
<md-icon md-svg-icon="action:ic_favorite_24px" aria-label="fav "></md-icon>
```

And this is my app.component.ts:

```
constructor(iconRegistry: MdIconRegistry, sanitizer: DomSanitizer, public dialog: MdDialog) {
    iconRegistry.addSvgIconSetInNamespace('action', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('./assets/img/svg/svg-sprite-action-symbol.svg'));
    iconRegistry.addSvgIcon('thumbs-up', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('./assets/img/svg/thumbup-icon.svg'));
    ...
    ...
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No not really.
At least inside a button or a link it works.

<button md-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()"> <md-icon svgIcon="navigation:menu">Menu</md-icon></button>

but not as standalone.

Comment: This was my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071885/md-icon-loaded-using-addsvgiconsetinnamespace-appear-in-the-dom-but-are-not-visi

Comment: Very nice hint. it makes things a little bit more clear to me. But still, I can use the SVG-images only within a button or a link. But it's quite some time ago I tried it. I'll have t update the libraries to a current state and try it again.
So thank you for the link.